# Queue demonstration in UML activity diagram

Tags: queue, uml, diagram, flowchart

I am trying to demonstrate  data input from UI. When a form is submitted by a user, data goes to MSMQUE, on the other side another application is listening MSMQUE. I thought it would be using `signal send`, and `signal receive` notation is an appropriate way to demonstrate the situation. However, I am not sure whether this is true. If the below diagram is wrong, please explain how it should be.

[image]

Comment: Do you specifically need to present it on activity diagram? Maybe you should consider sequence diagram instead?
I don't say it is impossible to present it on ad, just sd seems a better solution, unless you want to put it in some much broader context.

Comment: Actually it could be, however there is no need to create all diagrams for that project. activity diagram is quite enough so that I want to demonstrate in activity diagram.

Answer (score 3):

As @Ister said, a SD would highlight technical aspects better. There is also not a single solution for a queue. Here is one that sprung from my mind

[image]

The client just sends something to the queue and continues (it's incomplete). The server has two parallel process parts: one that receives events and queues them and a second that busy waits for something to get in the queue and then asynchronously schedules a task. Analogously a client can wait for async queue tasks or busy wait. There are tons of different ways to implement queues.